# How to prove norm equivalence?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I need help with description all $a\in l_\infty$ such that norm in
$l_1$ which equal
${|\|x\||}\_a = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty|a_k x_k|$
will be equivalent to
$||\cdot||_1$

To prove that I decided to consider unit vectors from $l_\infty$

I could estimate from above this sum using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality this way
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty|a_k x_k| \leq ||a||_\infty||x||_1 \leq ||x||_1$
But I can't estimate it from below

I hope you'll help me

Comment: What happens if there doesn't exist any constant $C>0$ such that $\forall k$, $|a_k|\geq C$?

Comment: What about $\liminf a >0$

Answer (score 1):

If $\liminf_n a_n =0$ then for the sequence $(e^{(n)})_{n\ge1} $ where $e^{(n)}_k=\delta_{n,k}$ you have that $\|e^{(n)}\|_1=1$. What can you say about $\|e^{(n)}\|_a $?

On the over hand, if $\liminf_n a_n \ge ε>0$ then there exists $n_0$ such that for $n \ge n_0$ you have that $a_n \ge \varepsilon $ and so
$$ \sum_{i=n_0}^\infty |a_ix_i| \ge \varepsilon \sum_{i=n_0}^\infty |x_i| .$$
Take $M= \max \{|a_1|, \dots , |a_{n_0-1}|, \varepsilon\}$  then $\|x\|_a \ge M \|x\|_1$.